# Rails model generator  from existing database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have configured two Servers:

- `serverA`:192.168.11.16 => running MySQLserver that contains many database with many tables.

  - one of the databases is `info`
  - one of the tables in this database is `table1` that contains info about users (name, no, id, addrs, etc.).
- `serverB`:192.168.11.17 => Running Rails3

Now I am going to connect to existing database(`info`) that is defined on `serverA` via Rails(`serverB`) then execute my query (`select name from tables1 where no >=1980`) & display the results of my direct query on rails webpage.

how to config `database.yml` to connect to existing database on `serverA` & display users' information on webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Your database.yml should contain

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: mysql
  username: <username>
  password: <password>
  host: 192.168.11.16

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: info
```

Also remember to specify the username and password info.

Comment: Thanks alot for reply,BUT where i  write query ,now i am going to connect to existing database(info) that is defined on serverA via Rails(serverB) then execute my query ( " select name from tables1 where no >=1980" ) & display the results of my direct query on rails webpage..& how to generate tables(table1) as a model ?when i issu the command: "rails generate model table1"- table1 is defined on serverA",the result is empty..table1 model is empty

Comment: when issue the command: rails generate model table1  get the following errors:
      invoke  active_record
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:196:in `merge!': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:196:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:190:in `each_slice'